# Compatibility between cypress and react-apollo

Tags: xmlhttprequest, fetch, apollo, react-apollo, cypress

I am using [react-apollo](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo) to make GraphQL queries, and I am using [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) for testing.

The problem is that these 2 dont seem to play well along. Apollo seems to be making all its requests through the Fetch API.

[image]

But Cypress seems like it is not able to capture anything, except XHR requests.

So what could I do to solve this problem? Is there a way for Cypress to capture "fetch" requests? Is there a way for react-apollo to use "xhr" instead of "fetch"?

Comment: There is an open GitHub issue regarding this one: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/95
You could try the suggested workarounds, have a look at the thread.

Comment: I already looked at the thread, but I kinda got lost on the discussion, and did not manage to understand the workarounds...

Answer (score 0):

Try out [`cypress-graphql-mock`](https://github.com/tgriesser/cypress-graphql-mock)

You just pass it your `schema`:

```
const schema = fs.readFileSync('../../app-schema.graphql', 'utf8');
// alternatively, using a dumped introspection query:
// const schema = require('../../dumped-schema.json')

beforeEach(() => {
  cy.server();
  cy.mockGraphql({ schema });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy workaround is to use `whatwg-fetch`, which you'd add as a dependency via npm and then...

*cypress/support/fetch_to_xhr.js*

```
function fetchToXhr() {
  let polyfill

  before(() => {
    cy.readFile('node_modules/whatwg-fetch/dist/fetch.umd.js')
      .then((contents) => polyfill = contents)
    Cypress.on('window:before:load', (win) => {
      delete win.fetch
      win.eval(polyfill)
    })
  })
}

fetchToXhr()
```

*cypress/support/index.js*

```
import "./fetch_to_xhr";
```

After that cypress will capture the graphql requests

Answer (score 0):

Cypress now officially supports working with GQL: [Working with GraphQL](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/testing-strategies/working-with-graphql#Expectations-for-Query-or-Mutation-Results).

I recommend reading their documentation in detail, but at your own risk here is a VERY crude TLDR:

```
cy.intercept('your-url-here/graphql', (req) => {
    const { body } = req;
    if (body.hasOwnProperty('your-operationName-here')) {
        // do something with the request, like:
        req.reply('your-mock-here');
    }
  });
```